# Regular expressions: extract numbers separated by commas from strings

Tags: c#, .net, regex, powershell

I need to extract numbers separated by commas from strings like this (with an arbitrary count of numbers and spaces):

```
Expression type:            Answer:
(1, 2,3)                    1,2,3
(1,3,4,5,77)                1,3,4,5,77
( b(2,46,8,4,5, 52)    y)   2,46,8,4,5,52
(a (3, 8,2, 1, 2, 9) x)     3,8,2,1,2,9
```

Comment: a) Which parts of this are variable? b) What have you tried?

Comment: The variable would be numbers like this: (number ,number,...,number) numbers in the brackets can be with spaces. I was using simple split technique but this is not elegant and error prone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the exaclty search string you willl always have like you posted it?

(number1,number2,numer3) text...

Edit: You provided new examples this should handle them:

```
    string input = "( b(2,46,8,4,5, 52)    y)";
    input = input.Remove(" ","");
    var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\(([0-9]+,)+[0-9]+\)");
    Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```

Comment: That's true - but his question doesn't show other cases. Im not sure what he needs

Comment: This code will also match numbers separated by spaces, e.g. `(1 2,3)`, but won't match single numbers, e.g. `(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this pattern:

```
\((?:\s*\d+\s*,?)+\)
```

For example:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(input, @"\((?:\s*\d+\s*,?)+\)");
Console.WriteLine(results[0].Value); // (1,2,3)
```

---

If you'd like to convert this to a list of integers you can do this fairly easily with Linq:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(input, @"\((?:\s*(\d+)\s*,?)+\)")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .SelectMany(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>()).Skip(1)
                   .SelectMany(g => g.Captures.Cast<Capture>())
                   .Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Value));
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var results = 
    from m in Regex.Matches(input, @"\((?:\s*(\d+)\s*,?)+\)").Cast<Match>()
    from g in m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1)
    from c in g.Captures.Cast<Capture>()
    select Convert.ToInt32(c.Value);
```

Comment: That will capture the individual numbers (with their trailing commas), not the entire `(1,2,3)`.

Comment: @m.buettner Sure it will. `results[0].Value` will be `(1,2,3)`

Comment: Oh right. Apparently, it's still too early over here... You could make that group non-capturing though `(?:\d+,?)` ... just as good practice, I think.

Comment: Your regular expression will match numbers separated by spaces (`(1 2)`) as well as number sequences with a trailing comma (`(1,2,)`), but not with a leading comma (`(,1,2)`).

Answer (score 1):

Seeing there could also be spaces, here is a suggestion, that [unrolls the loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) (which is a bit more efficient for larger inputs):

```
@"[(]\d+(?:,\d+)*[)]"
```

You can of course escape the parentheses with backslashes, too. I just wanted to show an alternative, which I personally find more readable.

If you eventually want to get the numbers, instead of splitting the result of the regex, you can capture them right away:

```
@"[(](?<numbers>\d+)(?:,(?<numbers>\d+))*[)]"
```

Now the group `numbers` will be a list of all the numbers (as strings).

I totally forgot about the spaces again, so here it is with spaces (which are not part of the captures):

```
@"[(]\s*(?<numbers>\d+)\s*(?:,\s*(?<numbers>\d+)\s*)*[)]"
```

Comment: Although I agree it's more readable, this doesn't account for spaces. Also I didn't know you could reuse group names like that.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Due to the fact he doesn't want to have the spaces in his result i would remove them before using regex.

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep +1 because that fully answers OP's problem. But would it be more efficient to strip them out after the match though since the size of the string would be smaller?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I think it's faster to remove them before you search with regex. But this is a guess i didn't measure it

Comment: @p.s.w.g somehow between my first sentence and the pattern I totally forgot about the space again o.O ... I'll make an edit. About the group name, that is only possible in .NET, and one of the engine's most useful features, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use a regular expression like this:

```
\((\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)\)
```

with PowerShell code like this:

```
$str = @(
    "(1, 2,3)"
  , "(1,3,4,5,77)"
  , "( b(2,46,8,4,5, 52)"
  , "(a (3, 8,2, 1, 2, 9) x)"
  , "(1)"
  , "(1 2, 3)"    # no match (no comma between 1st and 2nd number)
  , "( 1,2,3)"    # no match (leading whitespace before 1st number)
  , "(1,2,3 )"    # no match (trailing whitespace after last number)
  , "(1,2,)"      # no match (trailing comma)
)
$re  = '\((\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)\)'

$str | ? { $_ -match $re } | % { $matches[1] -replace '\s+', "" }
```

The regular expression will match a (sub)string that starts with an opening parenthesis followed by a comma-separated sequence of numbers (which may contain any number of whitespace before or after a comma) and ends with a closing parenthesis. The whitespace is subsequently removed by the `-replace` instruction.

If you don't want to match single numbers (`"(1)"`), change the regular expression to this:

```
\((\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)+)\)
```

If you want to allow whitespace after the opening or before the closing parenthesis, change the regular expression to this:

```
\(\s*(\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)\s*\)
```